# Import sub view to another view

Tags: views

It's possible to export sub view and import it to another view? For example I have views "A" & views "B" and each one has sub views [blocks - pages - ...etc]. How to export sub view from A to B?

Comment: Why you need that? Can't  you use single view?

Comment: Because the project built on views & sub views

Comment: No I mean need of importing a subview into another one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be needing this module [views_field_view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to insert a sub view inside a view as a field.

Comment: No, not that way, i want change the sub view instead of under A view to be under B view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, how do you export a page view, into another page view so that it has 2 page views and they can share the same theme template?

Nevermind I don't think that would be possible because each view would have its own machine name and it doesn't look like there is a tpl suggestion that would work for 2 views. So not to hijack but is there any way to have more than one view share the same theme file?

OK so here is the solution I used:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_template

It does just what I need and probably you too.